# client-side geometry in Esri Web AppBuilder

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have two csv files one contains lon/lat for a set of points, and the other one contains the links between those points (each row represents a link by the Object ID of the origin and destination of the link). Using ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.2 and D3 (used d3 to read csv) I was able to create two FeatureLayers and add them to the map. Now I want implement the same concept in ArcGIS Web AppBuilder, but I couldn't figure which of the files I should modify to include client-side geometry.

Comment: Not sure if WAB in ArcGIS online has this capability.  If not, and if you're using Portal, I'd look into writing a custom WAB widget using the WAB dev edition.

Comment: Actually I am using WAB dev edition. If I am understanding correctly, in WAB all customized functionalities are implemented through widgets? Is it possible to hide a custom widget from the user, while it does something automatically after the map is being loaded (here e.g. create a FeatureLayer from a CSV and add that to the map)? In fact, I prefer the layer being added to the map without interaction with the user, and not having a button for that on the interface.

Comment: Sorry, I thought in your use case the user would be dragging and dropping a csv onto the browser.  Are you saying the csv resides on the server?

Comment: Yes, CSV resides on the server. By client side, I only meant the geometry objects are created on the client side.

Comment: Probably a custom widget would still be the way to go.  Is WAB dev edition at 4.2 already? I think it usually lags behind the latest release a bit.

Comment: I finally implemented this through a widget. it requires the user to click on the widget to create a new featurelayer from the csv files and add that to the map. Web AppBuilder use ArcGIS JS API 4.2 for 3D apps and 3.19 for 2d apps.

Comment: But I am still looking for a way to add a layer when the map is loading (a layer other than those in the initial map, or webScene). I may edit this question to make it more general (i.e. about any layer, not specifically a layer based on client-side geometry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to load a widget when a a Web Appbuilder application loads edit the application's `config.json` to put the reference to the widget in the same array as the onscreen widgets like the scalebar and overview map. Widgets like this should have `"hasUIFile":false` and `"inPanel":false` in the properties section of their `manifest.json`.